# How can the frequency of dandelion++ stem tx observations in mainnet be increased?

Tags: dandelion++

I am interested in the anonymity of dandelion++ and am trying to find out how stem tx can be viewed in real communication.
From the [monero github source code changes made during the introduction of dandelion++](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6314), I found that for stem tx, I can observe packets where the value of the "dandelionpp_fluf" section is 00 (false).

Then, I set up a full node on mainnet (GUI version: 0.18.3.1-unknouwn(Qt 5.15.10)) and waited for the arrival of the corresponding packet while monitoring the communication with wireshark.

However, the relevant packets can only be observed once a day at most, which is too few samples to analyze.

Please let me know if there is any way to set up the system so that we can observe more stem tx.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can observe more by running a reliable, well-connected node. Increase your incoming and outgoing connections.